# vue js input скрыть текст если в нем есть подстрока

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование, vue.js, frontend

есть такой элемент на странице

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control"
 v-if="partner.email.includes('fake@fake.fake')"
 :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('email') }"
 v-text="false"
 v-model="form.email">
```

я пытаюс сделать так чтобы если мыло содержит подстроку fake@fake.fake юзер видел пустое поле и мог бы туда вписать свое реальное мыло. Проблема вв том что v-model как я понимаю биндит это с данными и сразу отображает то что там есть. 
Как можно скрыть текст в инпуте если он содержит подстроку но оставить возможность его редачить не потеряв связь с самим атрибутом?

Comment: что такое подстрока ?

Comment: placeholder не подходит?

Comment: ну часть текста которая в строке встречается. Тоетсь у меня фейковые мейлы начинаюстся с fake@fake.fake и к  ним при соединен еще шифр. Я хочу вычислть в личном кабинете, если мейл содержит такой текст то не отображать его, а давать юзеру возможность вписать свою существующую почту

Comment: placeholder  похду переписывается вуем, поэтому нет, не помогает

Comment: вообще я эту пробелему решил в беке, но если вдруг есть возможность такое провернуть на фронте, было бы интересно узнать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот такой вариант. Если передашь в setValue то что нужно игнорить, то подстрока удалится, но и между тем сохраниться возможность запилить такое же мыло в инпут, вдруг у кого то как раз такое)

```
<div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-on:input="checkField" :value="setValue('fake@fake.fake')">
    <button @click="getText">
        Test
    </button>
</div>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        ignoreValueReg: /fake\@fake.fake/gi, 
        text: ''
    },
    computed: {
        setValue () {
            return (defaultParam) => {
                if (defaultParam) {
                    return defaultParam.replace(this.ignoreValueReg, '')
                }else{
                    return this.text.replace(this.ignoreValueReg, '')
                }
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        checkField (e) {
            this.text = e.target.value;
        },
        getText () {
            console.log(this.text)
        }
    }
});
```